# FFMPEG Re-encode video after concatenation with complex filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a bash script for FFMPEG which accepts two inputs `Awoo.mkv` and `Awoo1.mkv`.

```
./ffmpeg -y \
    -i Awoo.mkv \
    -i Awoo2.mkv \
```

These two files are concatenated using a complex filter, this is because in the future files with different codecs will be concatenated as well. Two outputs from this filter are created `[outv]` and `[outa]`.

```
-filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
-map '[outv]' -map '[outa]' \
```

The video is then re-encoded with various settings into two separate streams. Stream v:0 and a:0 is in 1080, stream v:1 and a:1 is in 720.

```
-c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 4000k -s:v:0 1920x1080 -r:v:0 30 -g:v:0 90 -preset:v:0 superfast -tune:v:0 zerolatency -level:v:0 4 -pix_fmt:v:0 yuv420p -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 512k \
-c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 2500k -s:v:1 1280x720  -r:v:1 30 -g:v:1 90 -preset:v:1 superfast -tune:v:1 zerolatency -level:v:1 4 -pix_fmt:v:1 yuv420p -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 256k \
```

The final output is in HLS so some details for that are included

```
-hls_time 6 \
-hls_list_size 2 \
-hls_flags delete_segments \
-f hls -master_pl_name "${name}.m3u8" \
```

The re-encoded output streams are then mapped, at this point there are two outputs for the different quality settings.

```
-map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:v -map 0:a \
```

A variant stream mapping is then defined to include both output streams into the m3u8 playlist.

```
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" \
```

And finally some extra details for HLS.

```
-hls_segment_filename "sequence/${name}_%v-%d.ts" \
"sequence/${name}_%v.m3u8"
```

The is the entire script.

```
name=gw

./ffmpeg -y \
    -i Awoo.mkv \
    -i Awoo2.mkv \
    -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
    -map '[outv]' -map '[outa]' \
    -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 4000k -s:v:0 1920x1080 -r:v:0 30 -g:v:0 90 -preset:v:0 superfast -tune:v:0 zerolatency -level:v:0 4 -pix_fmt:v:0 yuv420p -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 512k  \
    -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 2500k -s:v:1 1280x720  -r:v:1 30 -g:v:1 90 -preset:v:1 superfast -tune:v:1 zerolatency -level:v:1 4 -pix_fmt:v:1 yuv420p -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 256k  \
    -hls_time 6 \
    -hls_list_size 2 \
    -hls_flags delete_segments \
    -f hls -master_pl_name "${name}.m3u8" \
    -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:v -map 0:a \
    -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" \
    -hls_segment_filename "sequence/${name}_%v-%d.ts" \
    "sequence/${name}_%v.m3u8"
```

I know that without the concatenation filter and a single input this script works fine, i'm having trouble working out how exactly I can work the concatenation filter into it, especially with the mapping command and how it works.

If I try to run this script in it's current state I get the error:

```
[hls @ 0x6a30180] Unable to find mapping variant stream
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
```

This is the entire output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Awoo.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:02:24.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1114 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29 fps, 29 tbr, 1k tbn, 58 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      CREATION_TIME   : 2017-01-27 05:02:53
      LANGUAGE        : und
      HANDLER_NAME    : VideoHandler
      DURATION        : 00:02:24.310000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      DURATION        : 00:02:24.348000000
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'Awoo2.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:02:24.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1114 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29 fps, 29 tbr, 1k tbn, 58 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      CREATION_TIME   : 2017-01-27 05:02:53
      LANGUAGE        : und
      HANDLER_NAME    : VideoHandler
      DURATION        : 00:02:24.310000000
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      DURATION        : 00:02:24.348000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat:in0:v0 (graph 0)
  Stream #0:1 (vorbis) -> concat:in0:a0 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:1 (vorbis) -> concat:in1:a0 (graph 0)
  concat:out:v0 (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:3 (vorbis (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:4 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:5 (vorbis (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x6a35bc0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x6a35bc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x6a35bc0] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x6a35bc0] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x3 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=4 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=1 slices=4 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=90 keyint_min=9 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=2500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x6a02980] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x6a02980] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x6a02980] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x6a02980] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x6b72640] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x6b72640] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x6b72640] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x6b72640] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x3 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=4 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=1 slices=4 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=90 keyint_min=9 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=4000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[hls @ 0x6a30180] Opening 'sequence/gw_0-0.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x6a30180] Opening 'sequence/gw_1-0.ts' for writing
Output #0, hls, to 'sequence/gw_%v.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 4000 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/4000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 512 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
    Stream #0:2(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 2500 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      CREATION_TIME   : 2017-01-27 05:02:53
      LANGUAGE        : und
      HANDLER_NAME    : VideoHandler
      DURATION        : 00:02:24.310000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/2500000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      DURATION        : 00:02:24.348000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
    Stream #0:4(und): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29 fps, 29 tbn, 29 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      CREATION_TIME   : 2017-01-27 05:02:53
      LANGUAGE        : und
      HANDLER_NAME    : VideoHandler
      DURATION        : 00:02:24.310000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      DURATION        : 00:02:24.348000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
frame=   41 fps=0.0 q=18.0 q=17.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.46 bitrate=N/A du
[hls @ 0x6a30180] Unable to find mapping variant stream
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution, I added an extra filter that does the exact same thing and only mapped the filter outputs:

```
name=gw

./ffmpeg -y \
    -i Awoo.mkv \
    -i Awoo2.mkv \
    -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1:[outv][outa]" \
    -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1:[outv][outa]" \
    -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 4000k -s:v:0 1920x1080 -r:v:0 30 -g:v:0 90 -preset:v:0 superfast -tune:v:0 zerolatency -level:v:0 4 -pix_fmt:v:0 yuv420p -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 512k  \
    -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 2500k -s:v:1 1280x720  -r:v:1 30 -g:v:1 90 -preset:v:1 superfast -tune:v:1 zerolatency -level:v:1 4 -pix_fmt:v:1 yuv420p -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 256k  \
    -map [outv] -map [outa] -map [outv] -map [outa] \
    -hls_time 6 \
    -hls_list_size 2 \
    -hls_flags delete_segments \
    -hls_segment_filename "sequence/${name}_%v-%d.ts" \
    -master_pl_name "${name}.m3u8" \
    -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" \
    -f hls "sequence/${name}_%v.m3u8"
```

If anyone knows any issues that this will cause, potential overhead, or any improvements what-so-ever I'd be happy to hear it.